# print chosen method of scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

This is a short question, but google points me every time to the documentation where I can't find the answer.

I am using scipy.optimize.minimize. It works pretty good, all things are fine. 
I can define a method to use, but it works even if I don't specify the method.

Is there any way to get an output, which method was used? I know the result class, but the method isn't mentioned there.

Here's an example:

```
solution = opt.minimize(functitionTOminimize,initialGuess, \
                      constraints=cons,options={'disp':True,'verbose':2})
print(solution)
```

I could set the value method to something like `slsqp` or `cobyla`, but I want to see what the program is choosing. How can I get this information?

Comment: please show some code for what you tried so far and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think my question is very basic, so I don't need to give executable code

Comment: I asked for an example because I assumed that by method you were referring to the objective function but now that I get your point, I hope that my answer helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [scipy-optimize-minimize-docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize): If no method is specified the default choice will be one of BFGS, L-BFGS-B, SLSQP, depending on whether the problem has constraints or bounds. To get more details on the methods deployement's order, you should take a look at the [scipy-optimize-minimize-source-code-line-480](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/485f4b4125304957eb1ef05e1dc8f8380a56714d/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py#L480). From the source code the order is the following:

```py
if method is None:
    # Select automatically
    if constraints:
        method = 'SLSQP'
    elif bounds is not None:
        method = 'L-BFGS-B'
    else:
        method = 'BFGS'
```

Comment: Ok, so I can't print it, I just  know what is chosen automaticly.

Comment: You can add a print statement to your local `scipy-optimize-minimize-source-file` for that or by using the knowledge of the algorithm and printing the `method` ahead in your main code.